# Как сравнить имя нужного мне процесса с папкой от куда запущен процесс

Tags: c#, процесс

Есть путь откуда запускается процесс svchost.exe - это папка System32.

Мне нужно из списка всех процессов найти этот процесс и сверить его с папкой System32.

Как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5497064/5752652

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно, там только получения путей от процесса и наоборот.

Comment: @Дмитрий, вы имеете в виду, что в предложенном дубликате нет информации о том как прибить процесс? Если да, то надо задать другой вопрос. Сейчас у вас 2 вопроса в вопросе, а надо бы придерживаться принципа SingleResponsibility)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Мне больше нужна информация как сравнить имя нужного мне процесса с папкой от куда запущен процесс. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Дмитрий, я немного не в теме того как это всё устроено, но разве в предложенном дубликате не то, что вам нужно? У вас есть имя процесса, в ответе там показано как узнать имя файла, запускающего процесс. Возможно там даже не просто имя, а полный путь к файлу, включающий вмещающую папку. Т.е. мой вопрос: вы попробовали предложенный вариант, посмотрели доку к методу/объекту и убедились что вам не подходит? Если да - опишите это в вопросе. В данный момент он выглядит так, что ответ-дубликат вполне подходит под вашу задачу.

Comment: Если тебе нужно сравнить запущенный процесс с файлом который лежит в папке System32, то можно так File.ReadLines(@"C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe").SequenceEqual(File.ReadLines(process.MainModule.FileName));